# PHP-Cli idsable unused Modules

Tags: php, module

im using PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u7 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 08:42:07)
with default config for apache and cli.
the most Modules which are loaded, not used by my application. So
is that possible to disable modules like: ftp / iconv / zip...
I cant find any config file with "extentions"

thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, run:

```
php -i
```

Then check the output for lines like these:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/cairo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
```

That will show you where the config files are located.

To disable a module, comment out lines like extension=module-name.so

Answer (score 0):

Check out your php.ini file! within this file you can disable modules (or uninstall them and keep your system clean!) You can also use the php.ini to disable to insecure functions of a package.
HTHs - Thanks!
//P